# Select last registered row from each group from two tables in MySQL v5.6

Tags: mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.6, group

Could you please help me with a query I'm having issues with? I tried to seach for similar questions here with no success.

I have 2 tables which I need to join and get the latest created_date from each val1, val2 unique combination.

See here for the 2 tables details: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/87hqeMqP7sf68fxbsywm5G/0

The expected result would be this:

| val1 | val2 | num1 | num2 | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | 33 | 333 | 2022-11-03 |
| X | B | 66 | 666 | 2022-11-06 |
| X | C | 88 | 888 | 2022-11-08 |
| X | D | 99 | 999 | 2022-11-09 |
| Y | A | 111 | 1111 | 2022-11-11 |

Please use MySQL v.5.6. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that 5.6 is past end of life and no longer receiving security updates.  Consider it insecure and plan to upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery would help in this case

```
SELECT d.val1, 
       d.val2, 
       s.num1, 
       s.num2, 
       mx_dt.max_dt
FROM scan AS s 
INNER JOIN dir AS d on s.t2id=d.t2id
INNER JOIN ( SELECT t2id, 
                    max(created_date) as max_dt
             FROM scan 
             GROUP BY t2id
          )   as mx_dt on mx_dt.t2id = s.t2id and mx_dt.max_dt=s.created_date;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/Owdaf5Lx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you gave me a great idea to group by t2id. This solution worked